# How to do a subquery on the same table in Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I have an Oracle table called item_association and an accompanying Hibernate Entity.  Here is an example of rows in that table:

```
id   group_id  item_id  type   value
====================================
1    1         1234     'lang' 'en' 
2    1         2345     'lang' 'fr'
```

I want to query that table to retrieve all ItemAssociations that share a group_id with a specific item_id, and exclude that item_id itself.  The SQL would be:

```
select group_id, item_id, type, value
from ITEM_ASSOCIATION
where group_id in (select group_id from ITEM_ASSOCIATION where item_id = :itemId)
and item_id <> :itemId
```

I am trying to use the following Hibernate criteria to accomplish that, but I get: `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: null`

```
DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(ItemAssociation.class)
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("itemId", itemId))
                    .setProjection(Projections.property("groupId"));

Criteria query = session.createCriteria(ItemAssociation.class)
                    .add(Property.forName("itemId").in(subquery))
                    .add(Restrictions.not(Restrictions.eq("itemId", itemId)));
```

ItemAssociation.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEM_ASSOCIATION")
public class ItemAssociation {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "group_id")
    private Long groupId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Item item;

    @Column
    private String type;

    @Column
    private String value;

    public Long getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    public void setGroupId(Long groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItemId(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one was just an oversight on my part.  Since the `ItemAssociation` entity contains an `Item` reference instead of the `itemId` field, I needed to change `itemId` to `item.id` in my queries.  Also, the first `itemId` in `query` is supposed to be `groupId`:

```
DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(ItemAssociation.class)
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("item.id", itemId))
                    .setProjection(Projections.property("groupId"));

Criteria query = session.createCriteria(ItemAssociation.class)
                    .add(Property.forName("groupId").in(subquery))
                    .add(Restrictions.not(Restrictions.eq("item.id", itemId)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use org.hibernate.criterion.Subqueries#propertyIn(String propertyName, DetachedCriteria dc)

```
(...)
Criteria query = session.createCriteria(ItemAssociation.class)
                .add(Subqueries.propertyIn("itemId",subquery))
                .add(Restrictions.not(Restrictions.eq("itemId", itemId)));
(...)
```

Comment: I still get the MappingException above when using Subqueries.propertyIn.